# SSL 3.0 support of paypal endpoints

Tags: ssl, paypal, sandbox

I can

```
curl -3 https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
```

to the normal endpoint using SSL 3.0. But I cannot

```
curl -3 https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

to the sandbox endpoint. I will get

> curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

I'm wondering when this was changed? Maybe today related to this POODLE thing released by Google?

Answer (score 0):

yes SSLv3 is disable
look here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-3t.sandbox.paypal.com%2Fnvp

Comment: But does anybody know if this was changed today?

Comment: Good question ... maybe. we can't know.

Comment: it's definitely been disabled in the Sandbox. I'm still looking for any official announcement of them having done it, or any timescales for doing it on their production systems.